# Why this class "font-weight-bold" doesn't work? [Bootstrap]

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1 class="h1">Bootstrap</h1>
    <p class="font-weight-bold">Palabra</p>
    <p class="font-italic">Palabra</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Adding "font-weight-bold" class to a p doesn't make any change to the text

[image: No change]

What can i do?

Comment: Your question refers to "font-weight-bold" but your code uses "text-weight-bold". Which is it?

Comment: looks like a typo, you are using `text-weight-bold` as your class, not `font-weight-bold` -> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/#font-weight-and-italics

Comment: Voting to close as "Typo"

Comment: Sorry, i just edited it! I tried with `text-weight-bold` because `font-weight-bold` didn't work

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's `font-weight-bold` for **Bootstrap 4**

And `class="fw-bold"` for **Bootstrap 5**

Comment: I edited it and i added `fw-bold` But it doesn't work yet.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 4 or Bootstrap 5

Comment: for fecks sake!

Answer (score 7):

Using `class= "fw-bold"` worked for me. I am working with bootstrap 5.

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/text/#font-weight-and-italics

Comment: Please don't repeat existing answers.

Answer (score 3):

**Bootstrap version 5**  `<p class="fw-bold">YOUR_TEXT</p>`

**Bootstrap version 4**  `<p class="font-weight-bold">YOUR_TEXT</p>`

**Bootstrap version < 4**  `<strong>YOUR_TEXT</strong>`

For the other styles such as normal and italic:

###### Bootstrap 4

```
<p class="font-weight-normal">YOUR_TEXT</p> // Normal
<p class="font-weight-light">YOUR_TEXT</p>  // Light
<p class="font-italic">YOUR_TEXT</p>        // Italic
```

###### Bootstrap 5

```
<p class="fw-bolder">Bolder weight text (relative to the parent element).</p>
<p class="fw-normal">Normal weight text.</p>
<p class="fw-light">Light weight text.</p>
<p class="fw-lighter">Lighter weight text (relative to the parent element).</p>
<p class="fst-italic">Italic text.</p>
<p class="fst-normal">Text with normal font style</p>
```

Comment: Font weights and the `strong` tag have different purposes. One is for styling. One is for _emphasis_ in a semantic sense.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `font-weight-bold` But you used `text-weight-bold` that's why your bootstrap class style is not working

Comment: after writing font-weight-bold you said this remains the same! So may be your link of css file is not working. check that properly

Answer (score 1):

Before version bootstrap 5 used `class='font-weight-bold'`, But bootstrap 5 use `class='fw-bold'`